# Save PDF file loaded in iframe

Tags: file, iframe, save

I am trying to save a pdf file that is loaded in an iFrame. There is by default a button in the iFrame to save the file but I want an extra button (outside the iFrame) to save the file.

```
<iframe id="labelFrame" src="loadedFile.pdf"></iframe>

<button id="savePDF">Download File</button>
```

**In javascript:**

```
 $('#savePDF').click(function(){
    var save = document.getElementById('labelFrame');
    //Save the file by opening the explorer for the user to select the place to save or save the file in a default location, how do I do this?
    }
```

What is the best way to reach this?

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

I needed an answer to this question as well and found a solution.

When displaying a PDF in an IFrame the browser will render it in an `<embed>` element and from there we cant use it in javascript as far as i know.

We'll need to use `XMLHttpRequest` to get the PDF from a server as a `Blob` object only then we can both display it and save it using javascript.

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('labelFrame'),
    saveBtn = document.getElementById('savePDF'),
    pdfUrl = 'loadedFile.pdf';

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", pdfUrl);
xhr.responseType = 'blob'; // <- important (but since IE10)
xhr.onload = function() {
    var blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(xhr.response); // <- used for display + download
    iframe.src = blobUrl
    saveBtn.onclick = function() {
        downloadBlob(blobUrl, 'myFilename.pdf');
    }
};
xhr.send();
```

The `xhr.onload` function will set to `src` of the iframe and add the `onclick` handler to the save button

Here is the `downloadBlob()` function that i've used in the example

```
function downloadBlob(blobUrl, filename) {
    var a = document.createElement('a');

    a.href = blobUrl;
    a.target = '_parent';
    // Use a.download if available. This increases the likelihood that
    // the file is downloaded instead of opened by another PDF plugin.
    if ('download' in a) {
        a.download = filename;
    }
    // <a> must be in the document for IE and recent Firefox versions,
    // otherwise .click() is ignored.
    (document.body || document.documentElement).appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    a.remove();
}
```